# How to remove some part from keyboard in react native app?

Tags: react-native, header, keyboard, custom-keyboard, react-simple-keyboard

I have an empty header on my keyboard (I mean the row above letters), how can I remove this part from the keyboard in my react native app? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEeGn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following props in your `<TextInput />`

- for android use: `keyboardType='visible-password'`
- for ios use: `autoCorrect={false}`

Comment: Perfect, it's working fine. Thanks